# $L/K \cong K$, then is $K=L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I would assume that the answer is yes, because $K \subset L$. Isomorphism implies that the cardinalities are the same, and so $L \subset K$.

But if the answer were so simple, then it would not exist as a question in a text, so I am wondering if my argument is incorrect.

Comment: $L/K \cong K$ doesn't mean anything in field theory

Comment: @reuns I think the OP means "$L$ is a field extension of $K$ which is isomorphic to $K$." But they should clarify.

Comment: I agree the answer is probably $K = \bigcup_n F(x_1,\ldots,x_n),L=K(x_0)$. Otherwise if $K$ is a subfield of $L$ the group/vector space quotient $L/K$ is a $[L:K]-1$ dimensional $K$-vector space so $K = \Bbb{Q},L= K(i)$ makes $L/K$ a 1-dimensional $K$-vector space.

Comment: "that the cardinalities are the same, and so $L \subset K$". Note that for every field $K$ except the finite fields $\mathbb F_q$, and every finite-dimensional extension $L\vert K$, the fields $L$ and $K$ have the same cardinality,

Comment: There is also $L = k(t),K= k(t^2)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I'm assuming that "$L/K\cong K$" means "$L$ is a field extension of $K$ which is isomorphic to $K$."*

Remember that infinite sets can have proper subsets of the same cardinality (indeed, that's sort of their defining feature). For example, take the natural numbers vs. the natural numbers greater than $1$. So your argument breaks down.

This is something you'll want to exploit: whip up a field extension $L\subsetneq K$ where the relationship between $L$ and $K$ is similar to the relationship between two infinite sets of the same cardinality. *HINT: Think about fields generated by adding, to a given starting field, a bunch of "indeterminates" ...*

Comment: I thought $L/K$ refers to $L$, the field extension of $K$. Are there grammatical rules in field theory? Or does my original question mean something else?

Thanks for the hint. The comments also allowed me to think of a counterexample, namely $\mathbb{Q}(x^2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. Then the mapping from x to $x^2$ would be an isomorphism, but one has no odd degree polynomials.